# Angular js - return and console.log $http response from outside the method

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, response, promise

Hi my code is very simple but i can't get to log the http result to this:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);

app.run(['contacts_helper','$rootScope', function(contacts_helper,$rootScope){
    var x = contacts_helper.getAll();
    console.log(x); // returns undefined 
  }]);

app.service('contacts_helper',['$http','$rootScope', function($http,$rootScope){

  this.getAll = function(){

    $http({
    method:'GET',
    url:'http://localhost/myjson.json',
    params:{id_user:$rootScope.session.id_user}

    }).success(function(response){

     return response;

    }).error(function(err){

     return false;

    });


    }


}]);
```

it always return `undefined` in console

So how to achieve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an AJAX call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)

Comment: You need to return the promise from the `$http` call, technically success and error functions haven't run yet by the time `x` gets assigned, thus x is `undefined`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your interface - you should make  `getAll` is a promise. You need to use `.then` to access its content:

```
contacts_helper.getAll().then(function(response){
  console.log(response); 
}]);
```

This is possible, by changing `getAll` to return the http call.

```
this.getAll = function(){

    return $http({
    method:'GET',
    url:'http://facebook.com',
    params:{id_user:$rootScope.session.id_user}

    }).success(function(response){

     return response;

    }).error(function(err){

     return false;

    });

};
```

Or even simpler:

```
this.getAll = function(){

    return $http({
    method:'GET',
    url:'http://facebook.com',
    params:{id_user:$rootScope.session.id_user}

    });

};
```

Also, you should probably read [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call/)

Comment: hey benji!! it works thanks! thanks i hope you didn't forgot about me :D have nice time mate ;)

Comment: @sbaaaang I did not, and frankly I think you should read that 'how to return the response from an AJAX call' post :) Good luck!